# Не записываются COOKIE, или записываются не всегда

Tags: php, cookie

Делаю авторизацию через куки, но почему-то раз работает, в остальных случаях нет...

Суть в чем, в файле список логинов и паролей

user1;pd1

user2;pd2

user3;pd3

```
if (isset($_POST['pas']) ){
for ($s= 0; $s <count($users); $s++) {
    /// Разделяем строку на пароль и логин 
    $pieces = explode(";", $users[$s]);

    print_r($pieces);
    /// Удаляем лишние абзацы 
    $pieces[0]=str_replace("\r", "", $pieces[0]);
    $pieces[0]=str_replace("\n", "", $pieces[0]);
    $pieces[1]=str_replace("\r", "", $pieces[1]);
    $pieces[1]=str_replace("\n", "", $pieces[1]);

    /// Если пароль совпал, записываем в данные сеси логин и пароль 
        if ($_POST['pas']==$pieces[1]){

            /// Устанавливаем куки на 10 минут 
            SetCookie("name",$pieces[0],time()+600,'dealer-arva.ru');
            SetCookie("pas",$_POST['pas'],time()+600,'dealer-arva.ru');

            $_COOKIE['name']=$pieces[0];
            $_COOKIE['pas']=$_POST['pas'];
            $i='1';
            echo "<script>
                setTimeout( 'location=\"main.php\";' );
            </script>
            ";
        }else{
            /// Если не совпал не делаем ничего 
        }

        /// Если не совпало ни с одним паролем перенаправляем на страницу ошибки
        if ($i==''){
        echo "<script>
                setTimeout( 'location=\"error.php\";' );
            </script>
            ";
        }
}
```

файл main.php должен просто выводить записаные куки print_r($_COOKIE);

если вводить первый пароль, все работает нормально, если второй или третий, первый скрипт вроде работает нормально, находит совпадение, и перенаправляет на main.php но массив $_COOKIE остается порожним.

Уже несколько часов ищу ошибку никак понять не могу в чем проблема. Может вам со стороны удастся помочь.

Comment: Не надо пихать пароль в куки!

Comment: та без разныцы, есть там пароль или любая другая информация, проблема в том ее вобще в куки добавлять не хочет

Comment: Вы не сможете поставить куки, если на страницу уже был вывод. Это ограничение протокола html.

Comment: хорошо, удаляю строчку print_r($pieces); вывода нет никакогоно не работает все равно

Comment: @KAGGDesign html - не протокол, и даже в http подобных ограничений в явном виде нет. Это просто особенность php, который не хочет заниматься буферизацией вывода (во многих фреймворках ровно наоборот - сперва собирается вывод, а потом к нему добавляются нужные заголовки, в Django или Flask например)

Comment: @arashvg у вас второй echo печатает скрипт после первого несовпадения юзера/пароля, и это тоже мешает заголовкам

Comment: @andreymal опечатка. Конечно, http.

Comment: @andreymal в http есть ограничение. message-headers не могут быть внутри message-body https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html. А куки - это header

Comment: вынес вывод скриптпта перенаправления за границы проверки, все стало работать. Спасибо большое!